# Rebind keys only in DrRacket interactions window

Tags: racket

I'd like to rebind

`C-up` to `"M-p : bring the previously entered expression down to the prompt"`

and

`C-down` to `"M-n : bring the expression after the current expression in the expression history down to the prompt"`

Racket behaves differently from my default terminal where I can use these control bindings to scroll through previous expressions.  The racket [manual](https://docs.racket-lang.org/drracket/Keyboard_Shortcuts.html) gives some examples of rebindings but does not explain how to rebind a key *only in the interactions window* which is what is needed here. What it's doing is keeping the same binding for C-up & C-down to mean move the cursor up and down, as is useful in the editor window, in the interaction prompt. But I don't think I want that as I can't see the use of it.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I have for my own use. Feel free to adapt it:

```
#lang s-exp framework/keybinding-lang

(require drracket/tool-lib)

(define (register-repl key command command-fallback)
  (keybinding key (λ (ed evt)
                    (define canvas (send ed get-canvas))
                    (send (send ed get-keymap) call-function
                          (if (is-a? canvas drracket:unit:interactions-canvas%)
                              command
                              command-fallback)
                          ed evt #t))))

(register-repl "d:up" "put-previous-sexp" "beginning-of-file")
(register-repl "d:down" "put-next-sexp" "end-of-file")
```